# react scroll to element when element exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm trying to scroll to an element in a long list after navigating to a page, however the element is not rendered immediately so at first there is nothing to scroll to.  I've tried three approaches with inconsistent or slow results:

1. scrolling to the ref'd element after a timeout
2. creating a div inside the element to scroll to which is passed the ref and a function the is called on mount to scroll to it.
3. a combination of 1 and 2

I've thought doing some sort of polling for the elements existence, but this feels kind of dirty for some reason.

Anyone have a better solution thats consistent and does not result in longer than necessary wait time before a scroll?

Answer (score 0):

To put the browser’s focus on a scrollable element after rendering, you have to consider few things.

You should give a tabindex attribute to your element and you have to set it to “-1” as follows.

```
<div tabIndex="-1">
     Your content.
</div>
```

Use React “ref”, instead of querying the DOM.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div
      tabIndex="-1"
      ref={this.myRef} >
      Your content.
    </div>
  );
}
```

Set focus on the componentDidMount lifecycle function.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current.offsetTop);
}
```

Comment: per the question, I have a div that calls the refdElement.scrollTo function in the 'componentDidMount' (actually using the useEffect vesion) but it's not working consistently.  Does focus work differently?

Comment: If you *want* it focused ... otherwise scroll the page

Comment: I have updated my answer. Main thing here is you have to call the scroll function inside the componentDidMount (else componentDidUpdate) as those function will trigger after the render process. Setting the tabIndex will help you to skip the default tab order.

Answer (score -1):

React has a "componentDidMount" lifecycle method that you can use to start your auto-scroll. You'll need to obtain the vertical position of your target element and then scroll the page by that much.

Comment: If you're rendering React into an already existing DOM element, perhaps immediately set page vertical position to that DOM element on load, then refine the position on componentDidMount. Maybe your scroll function can scroll faster? Maybe output an anchor from each LI and set window.location to the anchor upon componentDidMount? Any way you slice it, you need a DOM element already rendered (with styles already applied) to scroll to it. Maybe have React initially render "placeholder" LIs which get updated once the real data loads and you setState